# Can I configure WCF in project config file and not in main application Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have:
`CLIENT` layer
`FACADE` layer
`WebService` layer

The `FACADE` is calling the `WebService` and is there a way the client won't know about the `WebService` configuration and only the `FACADE` knows about it?

I have a project `MyWCF1.cproj` in `FACADE` which contains `web.config` file and inside it is the configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
...
</system.serviceModel>
```

How can I make calls to this WCF from `FACADE` project as for the moment I am getting 
"Could not find endpoint element with name ... and contract..."

When it is in the main `Web.config` it works fine, but when I put it `MyWCF1.cproj` does not work.

Here is the calling code example:

From ASP.Net

```
Facade f = new Facade();
MyObj obj = f.GetMeWhatIwant();

public MyObj GetMeWhatIwant()
{
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("MyUri"));
                        using (client proxy = new ServiceClient(endpointAddress))
    {
        offers = proxy.GetIt(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those projects in the same solution? You can't use `web.config` from other project, this is not working by design. Copy your configuration to the project you're running.

Comment: They are in the same solution, but are deployed then as presented in the updated question.

Comment: So then just copy `<system.serviceModel>` configuration to your running project.

Comment: No, you can't do that. This is how .NET was designed, from Day 1.